# How to setup OpenACS?

Tags: openacs

I am trying to setup OpenACS Project. I tried some Open Source Projects available on net. I am trying to setup OpenACS from below link.

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/OpenACS
```

But it is showing inactive and code is not there. Can i found this code somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Your link points to the "Automatic Configuration Server" (ACS), a project that unfortunately has a name-clash with the Open Architecture Community System (OpenACS). If you are referring to the latter, here you go:

http://openacs.org/xowiki/openacs-system-install

Answer (score 0):

You can find the official OpenACS code here: http://openacs.org/news/item?item_id=4197887

Two great installer scripts are located at github: https://github.com/gustafn/install-ns. It works great to get you up and running with a simple NaviServer, PostgreSQL OpenACS installation.

This should get you started!

Answer (score 0):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/OpenACS has a fork https://sourceforge.net/projects/libreacs/ and several its clones on github (I don't actually know which one is official). You'll find minimal installation instructions in **acs/doc/README** after cloning e.g.:

```
git clone https://git.code.sf.net/p/libreacs/code libreacs-code
```